# virtual и override

Tags: c++, c++11

Просматривая различные примеры (один из них: [Лекция. Виртуальные функции и полиморфизм](http://logic.pdmi.ras.ru/~smal/aptu/cpp10/2010_11_26.html)), увидел, что при использовании `virtual` можно переопределять метод производного класса. Также увидел, что даже если ссылаться на исходный класс — все равно будет вызван метод, переопределенный в дочернем классе, только если не указана область видимости метода.

Но (!) Я копаю кучу исходников С++ и вижу, что когда переопределяют метод в дочернем классе, то добавляют слово `override`. Однако в вышепоказанном примере никто `override` не пишет.

Так нужен он или нет? И вообще, что он дает, этот `override`? Везде написано, что он указывает на то что, метод переопределен, но в примерах его никто не использует, а в исходниках я его встречаю строго постоянно.

Помогите разобраться поконкретнее , `virtual` и `override` в С++ используются всегда только в паре или не всегда? И если не всегда в паре, то как это вообще влияет на выполнение кода?

Я просто пишу код и у меня выбивает ошибка на чтение нулевого адреса. Я думаю что что-то напортачил с этими виртуальными методами, хотя делаю все по шаблону.

Comment: Спасибо , вы мне очень помогли! =)

Comment: Если Вас удовлетворяет один из ответов, то примите его как правильный(галочка рядом с ответом)

Comment: Если чей-нибудь ответ решил ваш вопрос, то отметьте его "галочкой" (рядом со "стрелочками")

Answer (score 34, accepted):

`virtual` используется в базовом классе, чтобы сделать функцию виртуальной (полиморфной).

```
struct A {
  void f(); // обычная функция
};

struct B : A {
  virtual void f(); // виртуальная функция (перекрывает обычную A::f)
  virtual void g() = 0; // чисто-виртуальная функция
};
```

Также `virtual` можно, но не обязательно использовать в классах-потомках

```
struct C1 : B {
  void f(); // виртуальная, т.к. B::f виртуальная
  void g() = 0; // все еще чисто-виртуальная функция
};

struct C2 : B {
  virtual void f(); // виртуальная, т.к. B::f виртуальная
  virtual void g() = 0; // все еще чисто-виртуальная функция
};
```

`override` используется в классе-потомке, чтобы указать что функция должна переопределять виртуальную функцию, объявленную в базовом классе. Это позволяет избавиться от ошибок, когда из-за опечатки вместо переопределения существующей виртуальной функции была создана новая (с другим именем или сигнатурой).

```
struct C3 : B {
  void f() override; // гарантированное переопределение B::f
  void g() override = 0;
};
```

Допускается, но не рекомендуется использование `virtual` совместно с `override`.

```
struct C4 : B {
  // virtual не имеет смысла, т.к. override подразумевает virtual.
  virtual void f() override;
};
```

Кроме `override` существует спецификатор `final`, который запрещает переопределение виртуальной функции в классах-потомках.

```
struct C5 : B {
  virtual void f() final;
};
```

Comment: `override` и `final` это не ключевые слова, а идентификаторы со специальным (контекстнозависимым) значением.

Answer (score 12):

`override` как бы говорит компилятору - ищи эту функцию в классах предках выше, она виртуальна. (не найдет - выдаст ошибку) Без этого слова компилятор не найдя функцию у предков определит ее как новую функцию и ошибки не будет

Answer (score 7):

`virtual` и `override` — ключевые слова, используются для занесения методов в *таблицу виртуальных методов* (координирующую таблицу). Это такой механизм, используемый в языках программирования для поддержки динамического соответствия.

Обычно компилятор создает отдельную `vtable` для каждого класса. После создания объекта указатель на эту vtable, называемый *виртуальный табличный указатель* или `vpointer`, добавляется как скрытый член данного объекта (а зачастую как первый член). Компилятор также генерирует «скрытый» код в конструкторе каждого класса для инициализации vpointer-ов его объектов адресами соответствующей vtable. Координирующая таблица объекта содержит адреса динамически связанных методов объекта. Метод вызывается при выборке адреса метода из таблицы.

Comment: `override` и `final` это не ключевые слова, а идентификаторы со специальным (контекстнозависимым) значением.

Answer (score 6):

Когда мы объявляем функцию виртуальной, используя `virtual`, то это равносильно тому, как если бы мы обращались к ней не напрямую, а через указатель.

```
typedef void (*functionPointer)(ClassA*);

struct ClassA {
   functionPointer func1;
   bool called;
};

void callMe(ClassA* thisA) { thisA->called = true; }

ClassA ca;
ca.called = false;
ca.func1 = callMe;
ca.func1(&ca); // Будет вызвана функция callMe().
```

Поэтому при обращении к перекрытому методу всегда будет вызвана именно "последняя" версия функции. Даже если обращаться к ней, указывая класс-предок.

C помощью *override* можно избежать случайного поведения наследования в коде.В следующем примере показано, в какой ситуации без использования *override* поведение функции-члена производного класса может быть случайным.

Компилятор не выдает ошибки при использовании этого кода.

```
class BaseClass
{
    virtual void funcA();
    virtual void funcB() const;
    virtual void funcC(int = 0);
    void funcD();
};

class DerivedClass: public BaseClass
{
    virtual void funcA(); // ok, работает как подразумевается

    virtual void funcB(); // DerivedClass::funcB() не const, так что он не перекрывает
                          // BaseClass::funcB() const и является новым методом

    virtual void funcC(double = 0.0); // DerivedClass::funcC(double) имеет другой
                                      // тип параметра, чем BaseClass::funcC(int), так что
                                      // DerivedClass::funcC(double) тоже новый метод

};
```

Подробнее можно прочитать [здесь](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/jj678987.aspx).

Comment: Вы уж тогда ссылку дайте чтоб человек полностью почитал, это ж с документации msdn скопировано

Comment: То есть если мы будет везде писать override то если мы ошибемся с типом параметра или доступом, то нам компилятор укажет на ошибку, а если не писать то мы можем того не желая вызывать базовый метод, а если он еще и "= 0" то получить ссылку на NULL?

Comment: Если он `=0`, то такой код просто не скомпилируется.

Comment: Вот не знаю, щас почитал ваши всех ответы, и нашел ошибку. В бозовом классе был метод "=0", даже два таких, а производном их не переопределил и даже не создал. Все скомпилировалось и не было  ошибок. А при запуске программы при выполнении метода - краш

Comment: Видимо что-то с ключами компилятора. g++ обычно ругается на неопределённый `=0`.

Answer (score 1):

Возможность `override` появилась в С++ начиная с С++11. Ваши лекции и примеры в них были скорее всего изначально составлены еще до того времени и с тех пор не обновлялись.

Как вы сами [теперь] понимаете, `override` - это лишь средство самоконтроля, использование `override` является необязательным, т.е. работоспособность более раннего кода появлением `override` никак не нарушается.